# How can I comunicate from child to grandfather component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing one application with Angular 2. In my scenario there are three components:

- SearchComponent: this component call web service and inject result to SearchResultComponent.
- SearchResultComponent: this component expose my data inside one table.
- EditComponent: this component allow edit my data.

Below **SearchComponent** code:

```
<form>
    ... there my form input
</form>

<!-- result is a property inside my SearchComponent class -->
<search-result [(value)]="result"></search-result>
```

Below **SearchResultComponent** code:

```
<div>
    <table>
        ... there is my table
        ... foreach row I have one edit component
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>
                <edit></edit>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Below my **EditComponent** code:

```
<form>
    ... There are edit inputs...
</form>

<button label="Salva" (click)="edit()"></button>

<edit [(documentId)]="id"></edit>
```

My goal is that when I click on save button I would reload my result.

How can I reach the goal?

Thanks

Comment: So the thing is if you dont have a direct connection between the components it is always better to go with using Service to use a service, you can learn about it from https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to do this.
**1. Option:** Create a singleton service like @AsifKarimBherani suggested.

> ..The singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

In simple use cases in Angular 2+ you can achieve such result by providing the service **only** in the app.module.ts (*If using the standard file/folder structure from Angular-CLI*).

**2. Option:** Create a bridge from grandchild to parent and another bridge from parent to grandparent using **@Output** decorator.

> The child component exposes an EventEmitter property with which it
>   emits events when something happens. The parent binds to that event
>   property and reacts to those events.
>
> The child's EventEmitter property is an output property, typically
>   adorned with an @Output decoration

Hope this gave you some ideas.