# Angular: Access Grandchild and Nested Component Method with ViewChild

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, viewchild, angular10

Is there a way to control Grandchildren and Nested Components with ViewChild? I need to access/run a public method within a Grandchild component,  from a top layer. It doesn't seem to be working for me. Prefer not to utilize a service or input/output for now.

Its working for me, for only direct child components.

**Resources:**

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: Why not prefer a service? It should be done via service.

Comment: Can you please create an example in stackblitz of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you don't want to use a service, just add a public `ViewChild` property in both parent and grand parent , then from grand parent call `this.parentRef.grandChildRef.method...`

Answer (score 4):

Even though you said you would rather not utilize a service, that is probably your best option.

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52744815/10637527) solution.

Using `@ViewChild`, you can follow [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction?fireglass_rsn=true#parent-calls-an-viewchild) guide, with the grandchild component in the grandparent component.

Otherwise, you can create a 'bridge' from grandchild to parent, and then from parent to grandparent, using `@Output` decorator.

> The child component exposes an EventEmitter property with which it emits events when something happens. The parent binds to that event property and reacts to those events.
> The child's EventEmitter property is an output property, typically adorned with an @Output decoration

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46960013/10637527)

Example:

**Grandparent:**

```
<parent (notifyGrandparent)="GrandparentHandle($event)">
</parent>
 ///ts
GrandparentHandle(event){
// do needed work
}
```

**Parent:**

```
<child (handleNotif)="childEvent($event)">
</child>
@Output() notifyGrandparent= new EventEmitter();
childEvent(event) {
  this.notifyGrandparent.emit('event')
}
```

**Child:**

```
@Output() handleNotif = new EventEmitter
onNotify() {
  this.handleNotif.emit('notify everyone')
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56609105/10637527)

You can follow [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#bidirectional-service) guide for component interaction, with [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vkkglmovokax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) full stackblitz example.

Also, you can read [this](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8090) thread about component interaction

and [this](https://engineering.datorama.com/accessing-a-components-grandchildren-in-angular-ea15008828ea) example using `@viewChildren`, which is more interesting...

Comment: input output is utilized for solution, also the link you gave utilizes service

Answer (score 0):

The @ViewChild annotation allow to get a component from your View, using is type or using an hashtag

-- parent.component.ts

```js
@Component()
export class ParentComponant {

  @ViewChild("childComponent") child : ChildComponant;
  @ViewChild(ChildComponant) ifOnlyOneChildOfThisType : ChildComponant;
  
  // child are only accessible after view init
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.child.aPublicMethod();
     this.ifOnlyOneChildOfThisType.aPublicMethod();
  }

}
```

-- parent.component.html

```html
<h1> Hello i'm the parent component </h1>
<child-component #childComponent></child-component>
```

If your child componant need to use a method from the parent component, you can use Event or directly give the method to the child component thank to an Input.

If you give a method, you must declare it as arrow function else you will get the wrong "this" object.

-- parent.component.ts

```js
@Component()
export class ParentComponant {

  @ViewChild("childComponent") child : ChildComponant;
  @ViewChild(ChildComponant) ifOnlyOneChildOfThisType : ChildComponant;
  
  // child are only accessible after view init
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.child.aPublicMethod();
     this.ifOnlyOneChildOfThisType.aPublicMethod();
  }

  methodToShare = () => {
     // do something, and "this" is the ParentComponant
  }

}
```

-- parent.component.html

```html
<h1> Hello i'm the parent component </h1>
<child-component [inputMethod]="methodToShare" #childComponent></child-component>
```

If you have multiple child component you can use @ViewChildren annotation which allow you to get list of component inside a Query

Hop it help